# HANA get the most frequent value ("MODE")

Tags: hana

I need to create a procedure for a data set of values like `{1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5}` in my table (x) and the field name is (y).

I need to get the most frequent value in the set which is (3).
How to perform this?

I've tried to do

```
select MODE(y) from x
```

but I get an error

> invalid name of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculate the mode use this statement

> SELECT TOP 1 "y" FROM   x WHERE  "y" IS Not NULL GROUP  BY "y" ORDER 
>   BY COUNT(*) DESC

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQL Select statement

```
select top 1 distinct y from x order by count(*) over (partition by y) desc
```

if you wish to see the repeating count, you can use the following too

```
select top 1 distinct y, count(*) over (partition by y) cnt from x order by cnt desc
```

[image]
I hope it helps,